# does javascript's setInterval() method running consume noticeable processing power over time?

Tags: javascript, browser, setinterval

I'm wondering whether or not the periodic (every minute) activity of multiple instances of `setInterval()` running in the browser to tell time or maybe more labor instensive activities actually noticeably affects the browser and or OS performance.

And if they are noticeable, on what kind of time frame? Hours, days, weeks of leaving this webpage open on your browser?

thanks,
tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer you question, the function defined by `setInterval()` is cached, so besides the performance hit, (if the function is really intensive), there should be no noticeable effects to the browser/OS.

Update: If they are not noticeable on within the first few minutes, (assuming your code doesn't have huge memory leaks), they should be able to run indefinitely.

Comment: hi Jiange, thanks. that's good to know that `setInterval()` is cached. I'm not using setInterval to tell time. I'm using `new Date();` but the time is updating periodically. That's reasonable, right?

Comment: got me thinking, what exactly gets cached?

Comment: great, so in most cases one would know pretty soon whether their computer's fan kicks in or whatever that its not gonna go well? I've heard about memory leak but don't know how to measure that. Could you point me to some hands-on tutorials to learn more about this?

Comment: The function is cached like any other javascript function. Unless you are constantly adding memory to the browser instance, these functions should be stable.

Comment: No, its more like your page would become slow and unresponsive. May I ask what you are doing that has you so worried? For example if you're adding a string to an array every second, after a while, your browser will run out of memory, but if you're simply updating a value, it could continue indefinitely.

Comment: I'm just updating a value, the time. So I guess my worries are overstated. I hadn't realized that adding a value would be different than updating a value so now it is clear in my head. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem with `setInterval` is when your task takes longer than the interval you've given it. I choose to always use `setTimeout` instead. But if it's a long interval/ simple task, setInterval should be fine.

```
// update a clock 
function updateClock() {
    $('#clock').text(new Date());
}

function updateClockSetTimeout(interval) {
    updateClock();
    setTimeout(updateClockSetTimeout, interval);
}

function updateClockSetInterval(interval) {
    setInterval(updateClock, interval);
}
```

The best way would be to store the initial run time so you can schedule the next one depending on when this task actually finished.

Comment: hi Juan, telling time every minute seems pretty trivial so `setInterval` seems fine. I haven't used `setTimeout` yet. Can you give me an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: awesome Juan!  that makes perfect sense. I'll keep it mind for the future.

Comment: @timpeterson What I had before didn't work, it would only update it once in the setTimeout case,  it's fixed now